# Automation 31 templates or 1 template

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

am producing an excel report where I bring in data for one country via a data connection and then run a macro that refesh pivots and other sheets with that data and then closes and saves the Excel report for that country. For example Germany . I have then another 31 templates for other countries where the same process happens. The differences between the 31 templates is that the database sql query for the data connection ( bring records for Germany ) and the filename that it is saved as like Report_Germany .

In SSIS, I am using a process task that calls a vbs script which simply opens an excel file and runs a macros for each country . Now I do not want to create 31 different SSIS tasks.

Anyway I could use 1 Template and produce the required 31 Excel Reports in the same directory ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to use a single temple to create multiple reports.

All your pivot tables need to have a report filter equal to the country and all the data needs to be retrieved into one workbook.

Then you can loop through the countries setting the filters each time and saving the workbook as with a separate country name.

Listed below is some basic code to achieve this.

```
Sub Update_Pivot_filter()

Dim StaticArray(1 To 3) As String
Dim strName As String
Dim lCount As Long

StaticArray(1) = "Germany"
StaticArray(2) = "France"
StaticArray(3) = "Italy"


For lCount = LBound(StaticArray) To UBound(StaticArray)

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable1"). _
     PivotFields("Name").CurrentPage = StaticArray(lCount)
' Change report filter on a pivot table

    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
' Refresh all pivot tables

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Temp\Report_" & StaticArray(lCount) & ".xlsx", _
         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
' Save the file with a name matching the filter name

 MsgBox StaticArray(lCount)

Next lCount

End Sub
```

The downside of this approach is that each workbook contains all your data.

Comment: Good idea, but wont work as all the countries data together in one worksheet is too big for excel . Need something that will chnages the data being brought in for each country from the database and then refreshes the pivots inmy report and saves the 1st file as say Germany , Bring in the 2nd set of data and then refreshes and saves that as UK. 1 template and 1 macro. thinking about feeding in a variable into the data connection ( select * from table where country = 'Country 1' ) and when I save the file ( save as File_Country1 ) .

Comment: That sounds like a good approach and will allow you to have one template with multiple reports.